# how to autoplay next song in music application when first song completes playing

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I have made a music app using avtouchController & I want to play my next song one after the other using autoplay can u please give me the step to autoplay a song.

Comment: What is AVTouchController? I don't see a reference to it in the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you want to use [AVQueuePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010168).

Answer (score 0):

You should go to settings and set the play mode as sequential play mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AVFoundation, you can just add a listener to your player, and make the end playback method to fetch the next track. You add the listener like so:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[player currentItem]];
```

And then you create your method, something like this:

```
    -(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
        AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
        //Fetch your next track from your plist, array, database or whatever
      }
```